# How to pass data from directive to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I've built a custom directive in my app which utilizes D3.js. I want to be able to make an API call to load more data when a user clicks on a node within my D3 visualization. This will require grabbing the data associated with the node which was clicked and passing it back to my controller. The controller then handles calling a function to retrieve more data.

To get started I'm simply trying to log the data associated with the node a user clicked in my controller. My problem is that this data is `undefined` in my controller.

Relevant directive code:

```
angular.module('gameApp')
  .directive('gmLinkAnalysis', gmLinkAnalysis);

gmLinkAnalysis.$inject = ['$location', 'd3'];

function gmLinkAnalysis($location, d3) {

  var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/app/gmDataVis/gmLinkAnalysis/gmLinkAnalysis.directive.html',
    scope: {
      data: '=',
      logNode: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope) {

      ...

      function click(d) {
        scope.logNode(d);
      }
    }
  };
  return directive;
}
```

HTML:

```
<gm-link-analysis data="connections.users" log-node="connections.logNode(d)"></gm-link-analysis>
```

Relevant controller code:

```
angular.module('gameApp')
  .controller('ConnectionsController', ConnectionsController);

function ConnectionsController() {
  var vm = this;

  ...

  vm.logNode = function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  };
}
```

If I replace `d` in my html with a string such as "hello world" (`log-node="connections.logNode('hello world')"`) it is properly logged. So clearly my issue lies in not properly passing my data as the parameter in my html. How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to specify the parameter in the call:

so in your directive it should be

```
function click(d) {
  scope.logNode({d: d})
}
```

here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/heavyhorse/7983y06k/

Answer (score 1):

You may pass a model attaching some methods into the directive but I personally prefer using **`$.broadcast`** service to keep my codebase cleaner.

Directive

```
function click(d) {
   $rootScope.$broadcast('someEvent', d);
 }
```

Controller

```
angular.module('gameApp')
   .controller('ConnectionsController', ConnectionsController);

 function ConnectionsController() {
   var vm = this;

   vm.$on('someEvent', function(event, data) {
     console.log(data)
   });
 }
```

If you still think that passing methods around would make the trick for you, here is a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/1xfvuotL/2/) passing a method to the directive via a data model

Comment: $broadcast is really convenient, but there is overhead associated with it (in terms of digest ect..) and creates maintainability problems later. BUT yes this does work.

Comment: @heavyhorse I highly disagree, using `$broadcast` you should only have "unmatched" events if any of the method names changes in the future. Method calls would be more accurate and data models will be less complex. Furthermore, debugging and type checking would be easier too.